# how to put cursor content in textview

Tags: java, android

hi i want to put cursor content in   textview .

im using sqlite data base when get the id of the current user and display them in a textview i tried to search but i found nothing 
here is the code

```
package com.example.i.projet;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AfficherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BaseDeDonee bdd;
EditText nom , prenom , email,numt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_afficher);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    bdd = new BaseDeDonee(this);
    int k =bdd.tempID();// to get id of corrent user
    String id = Integer.toString(k) ;
    Cursor res = bdd.afficherinfoP(id);// function return cursor 

    nom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    prenom=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    numt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.numtele);

  if(res.getCount()<=0){
      // show message empty
  }else{
      res.moveToFirst();
      nom.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nom")));
      prenom.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("prenom")));
      numt.setText(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("numero_tel")));
      email.setText( res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("profile")));

  }



}


}
```

and the data base

```
public class BaseDeDonee extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Platforme.db";

public static final String TABLE_PERSONNE = "UsersTable";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "nom";
public static final String COL_3 = "prenom";
public static final String COL_4 = "numero_tel";
public static final String COL_5 = "profile";
public static final String COL_s = "password";
public static final String COL_k = "etat";


public static final String TABLE_COMPTE = "CompteTable";
public static final String COL_6 = "numero_compte";
public static final String COL_7 = "cle_compte";
public static final String COL_8 = "solde_courante";
public static final String COL_9 = "type_compte";

public static final String TABLE_OPPERATIONS = "OpperationsTable";
public static final String COL_10 = "num_opp";
public static final String COL_11 = "type_opp";
public static final String COL_12 = "date_opp";
public static final String COL_13 = "montant_opp";
public static final String COL_14 = "solde_courante";
//+etat de l'opp pour avoir est que personel ou du busness

public static final String TABLE_PRODUITS = "ProductsTable";

public static final String COL_15 = "nom_prod";
public static final String COL_16 = "type_prod";
public static final String COL_17 = "PrixUnit_prod";
public static final String COL_18 = "quantite_prod";
public static final String COL_19 = "PrixTotal_prod";

public static final String TABLE_FACTURES = "FacturesTable";

public static final String COL_20 = "num_fact";
public static final String COL_21 = "type_fact";
public static final String COL_22 = "Montant_fact";
public static final String COL_23 = "date_fact";

public static final String TABLE_IDENTIFICATION = "IdentificationTable";

public static final String COL_24 = "profile";
public static final String COL_25 = "password";

public static final String TABLE_DECAISSEMENT = "DecaissementTable";

public static final String COL_26 = "num_opp";
public static final String COL_27 = "type_compte";
public static final String COL_28 = "piecejustificatif";

public static final String TABLE_Temp = "tempTable";
public static final String COL_29 = "ID";





public BaseDeDonee(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);



}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PERSONNE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nom TEXT,prenom TEXT,numero_tel INTEGER,profile TEXT,password Text,etat Text)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_COMPTE +" (numero_compte INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,cle_compte INTEGER,solde_courante DOUBLE,type_compte TEXT,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PRODUITS +" (nom_prod TEXT PRIMARY KEY,type_prod TEXT,PrixUnit_prod DOUBLE,quantite_prod INTEGER,PrixTotal_prod DOUBLE,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_FACTURES +" (num_fact INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,type_fact TEXT,Montant_fact DOUBLE,date_fact DATE,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_OPPERATIONS +" (num_opp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,type_opp TEXT,montant_opp DOUBLE,date_opp DATE,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE ,solde_courante DOUBLE REFERENCES TABLE_COMPTE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_IDENTIFICATION +" (profile TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE PRIMARY KEY ,password TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_DECAISSEMENT + " (piecejustificatif TEXT PRIMARY KEY,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS,type_compte TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_COMPTE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_Temp + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PERSONNE + TABLE_COMPTE + TABLE_PRODUITS + TABLE_FACTURES + TABLE_OPPERATIONS + TABLE_IDENTIFICATION + TABLE_DECAISSEMENT + TABLE_Temp);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String nom ,String prenom ,String tel,String profile,String password ,String etat){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_PERSONNE,new String[]{"*"},"profile =?",new String[]{profile},null,null,null);

    contentValues.put(COL_2,nom);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,prenom);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,tel);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,profile);
    contentValues.put(COL_s,password);
    contentValues.put(COL_k,etat);
    if(res!=null && res.moveToFirst()){
        return false;
    }else{
    long result=  db.insert(TABLE_PERSONNE, null, contentValues);

    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }else return true; }





}
public boolean insertl(String profile ,String password ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_24,profile);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_25,password);



    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean insertfacture(String type ,String Montantfact, String date){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_21,type);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_22,Montantfact);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_23,date);
    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_FACTURES,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean insertCompte(String numero_compte ,String cle_compte, String solde_courante,String type_compte ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_6,numero_compte);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_7,cle_compte);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_8,solde_courante);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_9,type_compte);
    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_COMPTE,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}
public boolean insertProduit(String nom_prod ,String type_prod, String PrixUnit_prod,String  quantite_prod,String PrixTotal_prod){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();

    ContentVlues.put(COL_15,nom_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_16,type_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_17,PrixUnit_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_18,quantite_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_19,PrixTotal_prod);


    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_PRODUITS,null,ContentVlues);

    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean inseloginid(int  id  ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_Temp,null);
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_29,id);
    if(res.getCount()<=0){
        long  result =db.insert(TABLE_Temp,null,ContentVlues);
        if (result==-1)
            return false;
        else return true ;
    }else return true;


}


public Cursor afficherinfoP (String id ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_PERSONNE,null,"ID = ? ", new String[]{id},null,null,null);

    return res;

}


public Boolean finde(String lemail, String lpass) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION, null, "profile=? AND password=?",new String[]{lemail,lpass},null,null,null);


    if(res.getCount()<=0){
        res.close();

        return false;
    }else {
        res.close();
        return true;
    }

}
public int findID (String lemail){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int k ;
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_PERSONNE, null, "profile=?", new String[]{lemail}, null, null, null);
    if(res!=null && res.moveToFirst()){
        //cursor contains data
        int ind =res.getColumnIndex("id");
         k = res.getInt(ind);
    }else k=0;

    return  k;
}
public int tempID (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int k =-1;
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_Temp, null);
    if (res!=null && res.moveToFirst()){
         k = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    }

    return k ;

}
public double rapportJ(String date,int id ){
    Double k= Double.valueOf(0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from"+TABLE_FACTURES+"where date_fact="+date+"and id="+id,null);
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        k=k+ res.getDouble(2);
    }
    Cursor ress=db.rawQuery("Select * from"+TABLE_OPPERATIONS+"where date_opp="+date+"and id="+id,null);
    while (ress.moveToNext()){
        k=k+ ress.getDouble(2);
    }
    return k;
}
```

}

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Eg9.png)

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: no its not the app shut down when i enter the activity

Comment: Go ahead and post the stacktrace and also the BaseDeDonee class if you can.

Comment: Also is there a reason you're setting text on EditText views instead of Textviews?

Comment: in case i wanted to modifie the result on clicking on a button but i didnt do that yet

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace when the error occurs?

Comment: i added it @DanielK

Comment: What error is the stacktrace giving you?

Comment: i think the cursor is empty

Comment: Do you have any data on your tables already?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the following issues following your logic:

```
public boolean inseloginid(int  id  ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_Temp,null);
        ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
        ContentVlues.put(COL_29,id);
        if(res.getCount()>0){ // I changed this condition from  <= to >
            db.delete(TABLE_Temp,null,null); // added this line
            long  result =db.insert(TABLE_Temp,null,ContentVlues);
            if (result==-1)
                return false;
            else return true ;
        }else return true;


}
```

The reason is that it will not insert the current login if there is a previous value stored. After the correction, if there is a value stored, it'll clear the table and enter the login ID. In the main activity call `bdd.inseloginid(loggedID);` before `int k = bdd.tempID();`. That inserts the ID into temp then you pull it with `int k = bdd.tempID();`. That'll pull the correct data from the database when you call `bdd.afficherinfoP(id);`.

When it comes to displaying them with the EditText views:

```
numt.setText(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("numero_tel")));
```

returns a string because `"numero_tel"` is an integer in your table declaration, so turn it into a string:

```
numt.setText(Integer.toString(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("numero_tel"))));
```

There may be easier ways to do this but I tried to keep your logic intact. It's also worth mentioning that you have to clear `TABLE_temp` because in `bdd.tempID();` your logic always goes to the top value. If you clear the table then the top value will be the logged in ID.